# Integrating OpenCV in a OpenGL application

Tags: macos, opengl, opencv, window, glut

i'm working on an OpenGL project, now i've the need to show an OpenCV window in the same application.
After calling

`cvNamedWindow("OPEN_CV");`

before the `glutMainLoop` i got this error

`GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time.`

and only the OpenCV windows been showed.

How is possibile to have this? (maybe without using the OpenCV processed data as texture for another GLUT window)

Comment: I've just bumped into this too, though other way 'round: I am adding openGL to openCV project. If I put the glutInit and do my drawing  before making the namedWindow, I can get a teapot. After, I get that warning the OP describes, and no teapot or window.

Answer (score 0):

openCV highgui uses glut. Try createOpenGLCallback to draw inside an openCV window.